# Chrome doesn't close the notification

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, notifications

I'm currently using this implementation to use Browsers based Notifications :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notification

This works like a charm.

```js
if ("Notification" in window) {
        if(Notification.permission === "granted") {
            if($('#notify-on-message').is(':checked')) {
                var notification = new Notification(username + ' : ' + data, {'icon': "/custom/favicon.gif"});
            }
            if ($('#notify-on-hl').is(':checked')) {
                var patt = new RegExp("(^|\\W)"+selfusername+"(\\W|$)");
                if(patt.test(data)) {
                    var notification = new Notification(username + ' highlighted you.', {'icon': "/custom/favicon.gif"});
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The main issue I have is that on chrome based browsers, the notification just doesn't close itself after the 3 seconds delay.
It tried adding this after the `var notification = ...`

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    notification.close();
}, 2000);
```

Though that doesn't change a single thing. The notification remains.
Is it a known issue ? Is there an easy way to fix this behaviour I don't want ?

EDIT 1:
According to this page :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_Web_Notifications
This is a known issue :

> Note: Firefox and Safari close the notifications automatically after a few moments, e.g. 4  seconds.
>
> This can also be done at the web application level using the Notification.close() method, for example with the following code:

```js
var n = new Notification("Hi!");
n.onshow = function () { 
    setTimeout(n.close, 5000); 
}
```

Though that code doesn't work. There is an error in the console that says that the notification doesn't have the close method or something like that.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well actually I was wrong, the code

```js
var message_notification = new Notification("Data");
setTimeout(function(){
    message_notification.close();
}, 3000);
```

Works in both Firefox and Chrome. (And Safari too I guess)

Comment: Still curious why the advertised way (`.onshow`) doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe the documentation wasn't up to date or I was using a different version. Can't remember actually ^^"

Answer (score 0):

Adding a tag to the option will close active popup before showing new once

```
                            var options = {
                                body: msg,
                                icon: "logo.png",
                                dir: "ltr",
                                tag: "group1"
                            };
```